# Changing the Danger Zone of Tornado Alley

Tags: environment, climate, geography, geology, weather

I am currently at the end of my wits.  No matter what change I do to the North American geography, northeastern Nebraska (42.4649° North, 96.4131° West), is still in the danger zone called Tornado Alley.  (Heaven forbid, I've had more than enough experience with that reaper's scythe in my lifetime.)

Changing the Rocky Mountains didn't seem to help, despite increasing their maximum height from 14,440 feet above sea level to 20,308 feet, resulting in a plateau that should have been tall enough to block off one of the three types of air crucial in creating the Alley--warm, dry air from the Southwest.

Changing the Great Lakes or the Appalachians didn't seem to help, either because they don't directly influence the Midwest's weather patterns.

So what ***DO*** I need to change to put northeastern Nebraska ***OUTSIDE*** the Alley while at the same time retaining the Midwest's prairie fertility and hope of having a White Christmas?

Comment: The level of detail and nature of your attempts almost sounds like you have an actual simulation. Is this connected to a game or simulation, or is your wording that way to just add 'character' to your question?

Comment: No and no.  This is genuine.

Comment: How are you making these changes? How are you getting these results? I think clarifying that context will help us understand your question better.

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/49422/the-monstrosities-of-the-appalachian-mountains-and-the-great-lake-no-plural-s   http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48961/the-great-plains-between-two-taller-mountains

Comment: If you want to get rid of the tornadoes, why don't you get rid of most of the landmass? Nebraska becomes an island surrounded by water. Problem solved!

Comment: @Vincent  How does that guarantee that the Midwest would still have its prairie fertility and a possibility for a White Christmas?

Comment: Northern Japan at about the same latitude is one of the snowiest places on the planet. It's also fertile.

Comment: It's also not a good enough example--not even close.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: Because Japan is an island.

Comment: So does my proposition for an alternate Nebraska. Strange coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a decent sized (about the same as the Rockies) mountain range in the south central US? (Texas, Oklahoma, and Arkansas) This would dry out the air coming from the Gulf of Mexico, thus giving Tornado Alley less favorable conditions for forming tornadoes.
See the map on http://www.tornadofacts.net/tornado-alley-facts.php

Comment: Will this also guarantee the Great Plains' prairie fertility and a chance for a White Christmas?

Comment: The chance for a White Christmas wouldn't be affected because air masses from the arctic are responsible for that. The fertility would also remain pretty similar because there would still exist storms moving from west to east along the jet stream.

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, cold air from the Arctic is dry which means that Christmas will get cold, but not white.

Comment: There is a distinction between _arctic_ air masses and _polar_ air masses. Arctic masses are always dry. Polar masses can be either wet or dry. Both arctic and polar masses would still affect Nebraska weather.

Comment: All right.  So how do you mean "decent"-sized?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. A range with the height of Rockies would work. As far as land area covered, it should stretch from north central Texas through Oklahoma, Arkansas, and into Tennessee a little.

Comment: I just came back from looking up air masses.  Here's what I've found:  http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CQN6XAXIrvo/UKZjrvoKWEI/AAAAAAAAAXQ/rUuNMJjgcmU/s1600/airmasswinter.jpg

Comment: @JohnWDailey You still get snow...Canada is still white pretty much all over in the winter.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado Alley comes from the shifting dryline that is at the encounter of the dry air eastwards of the Rockies and the warmer humid air that comes from the Gulf of Mexico. Remove the Gulf of Mexico or add a mountain range in Southern US. That should fix it.

[image]

Comment: How do I justify a major mountain range so close to either the Rockies or the Appalachians?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered moving Nebraska? What about reversing the direction of the Earth's rotation?

If your story is more realistic, consider that NASA has theorized that they could dissipate hurricanes with a concrete tube, hundreds of miles long. Perhaps the tornadoes could be similarly dissipated with a large subway system.

Have you tried making the Rockies flatter instead of taller? It looks like the best bet for getting everything you're asking for is to move the position of the jet stream during the summer.

Comment: Flattening the Rockies will just turn the Great Plains into desert.  I don't want that.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe make a mountain range in the north Dakota - Minnesota area and a mountain range in central Texas, and raise the Appalachians so you get □ with mountains. If I'm right, tornado alley is a perfect place for tornadoes because of the warm air masses from the gulf area and cold air masses from Canada, they mix and create a swirl, and the land is flat, so by stopping the air masses from mixing, you've gotten rid of tornadoes!

Comment: I want Great Plains, not Western Interior Seaway.

Comment: The first part should be a comment, not an answer. The second part seems to not answer the question as asked.

Comment: It's getting better, but it's still hard to follow.